# How to disable VM Ware and VirtualBox from the command line?

Tags: windows, cmd, virtual-machine

I currently have VirtualBox and VM Ware on my laptop, but I want to get Hyper-V up and running on my machine.  How do I disable VM Ware and VirtualBox from the command line?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.